# Matrices up to an equivalence relation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the $n\times n$ matrices over a field $k$, $M_{n\times m}k$. Say that $A\sim B$ for $A,B\in M_{n\times n}k$ if there is an invertible matrix $C\in M_{m\times m}k$ such that $A=BC$.

Under this equivalence relation, a matrix is equivalent to its reduced column echelon form, right?

Hence, the equivalence classes may be represented by all reduced column echelon form matrices in $M_{n\times m}k$? Is that right?

Comment: Elementary row operations can be achieved by **left**-multiplying by elementary matrices, and an invertible matrix will therefore be a product of elementary matrices. Here you are **right** multiplying, so you are performing elementary *column* operations. You are not going to get a reduced row-echelon form by doing that, you are going to get a "reduced column-echelon form".

Comment: My mistake, will edit.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the terminology you are using, but two matrices are equivalent in this sense if and only if they have the same range.